# by vs with the hands

Tags: prepositions

Why would the answer for:

> When you first meet someone, you should shake them ______ the hands.

It's *by* and not *with*; the *by* sounds cumbersome to me, though *by using the hands* sounds ok to me.

While [here](http://www.englishgateway.com/ArticleVm.aspx?SectionID=d110128e12974f6bb118fcb081764008&ArticleID=738cc5bffe404472a0fbc07e5ba838ef) says that *with* is used when tools or parts of the body mentioned.

> *He pushed the door with his foot*.

Notice those *with his foot* and *by the hands*, how could they be different?

The site also confuse me even more by stating *by hand* means *handmade*, *made by a person, not by a machine*.

Comment: I think that page is not quite precise enough.  Yes, you usually say "with" if you are using a body part like a tool (as in "I closed the door with my elbow") but there are idiomatic phrases in which body parts are used are used with "by", usually meaning *by means of* in a generic sense.  For example, when we say a sweater was made *by hand* we mean "by use of the hands", not literally "using my hand".  Likewise, when we say "The musician played the piece by ear" we mean that he *learned it by listening to it*, not that he literally played the piano with his ear.

Comment: Also note that the sentence in the question is slightly wrong itself - you shake someone by the hand, not by the hand_s_.

Comment: @stangdon what a good comment! Then, what is the difference between 'He pushed the door with his hand' and 'He pushed the door by his hand'? I think that the former is describing he is using his foot or body pushing the door with his hand, but on the contrary the latter seems to be only describing that only his hand is pushing the door. What do you think about my opinion?

Comment: @EvaristeGalois - "He pushed the door *with* his hand" is the normal phrasing, meaning that he used his hand to push the door.  "He pushed the door *by* his hand" doesn't really make sense and is very nonfluent.  If I heard it, I would think the speaker meant "He pushed the door *that was next to* his hand"; it doesn't mean that his hand was pushing the door.

Comment: @stagdon 'By' means so similar to 'next to'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With refers to your hand. By refers to the other person's hand.

So, "I shook him with my hand" might mean you took hold of his ear or his foot and shook him. "I shook him by the hand." Means I took hold of *his* hand and shook it.

Similarly, "I opened the door with my foot," but "I opened the door by the handle."

But idiomatically you would simply say "I shook his hand."

Comment: +1, and special props for that last sentence. If I could add a footnote, using the O.P.'s sentence structure, I would probably say, "When you first meet someone, you should ***shake hands with them***.